# Showing that $(C_0([0,\infty)), \|\cdot\|_\infty)$ is complete.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, complete-spaces

I need to proof that $(C_0([0,\infty)), \ \|\cdot\|_\infty)$ is complete. I think that I did it correctly (or atleast am thinking in the right direction), but I still struggle with writing it down correctly. I used that $(C_b([0,\infty)), \|\cdot\|_\infty)$ is complete, so therefore as $C_0[0,\infty) \subset C_b[0,\infty) $, I wanted to use that if $A$ is a closed subset of a complete space $(M,d)$, that $(A,d)$ is complete. Thus, it came down to showing that $C_0[0,\infty)$ is closed.

Let $f_n(k)$ be a sequence of elements out of $C_0[0,\infty)$ that converges to an element $f$ out of $C_b[0,\infty)$. I need to proof that $f(k) \in C_0[0,\infty)$.

Per the definition of convergence, we know that $\|f_n(k) - f(k) \|_\infty \rightarrow 0$ whenever $n \rightarrow \infty$. We use this to find $ |f_n(k)-f(k)| \leq\|f_n(k) - f(k)\|_\infty  \rightarrow 0$.

Then we consider $|f(k)| = |f(k) - f_n(k) +f_n(k)| \leq |f(k)-f_n(k)| + |f_n(k)|$. If we take limits on both sides, we get: $\lim_{k\to \infty} |f(k)| \leq \lim_{k\to \infty} |f(k)-f_n(k)| + \lim_{k\to \infty} |f_n(k)| = 0 + 0 = 0$ (the first term follows from what we have previously stated and the second term follows from the fact that $f_n(k)$ is an element of $C_0$. Thus, $f \in C_0$ and therefore $C_0$ is closed and therefore it is complete.

My questions are the following;

- What exactly does it mean to be a sequence of functions?
- I used $f_n(k)$ and $f(k)$ in my proof because I saw that it was used in another exercise, but I'm not sure what it means to write that $k$ down.
- Is the structure of my proof sound?
- Is there a better way to proof such statements?

Thanks for reading,

K. Kamal

Comment: You need to show if $\|f_n-f\|_\infty \to 0$ where the $f_n$ are continuous then $f$ is continuous. Then do the same for the limit at $\infty$.

Comment: @reuns Do I really need to show that $f$ is continuous? It's an element from $C_b$ right? Therefore, it needs to be continuous I thought.

Comment: What is $C_b$, is it $L^\infty$ ? Of course the point is to show $f$ is bounded, continuous and $f(\infty) = 0$ so $f \in C_0([0,\infty))$

Comment: $C_b([0,\infty))$ are all the continuous, bounded functions on the interval $[0,\infty)$

Comment: How do you know it is complete ? Prove it ! (look at $|f(x)-f(x+h)| \le |f(x)-f_n(x)|+|f_n(x)-f_n(x+h)| + |f_n(x+h)-f(x+h)|$)

Comment: @reuns That was a given hint in the exercise.

Comment: Can you use what I wrote to prove $f$ is continuous and bounded ie. $C_b$ is complete ? If so then the limit at $\infty$ will be obvious to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $f_n$ is Cauchy, then since you know $C_b$ is complete you know
that $f_n \to f$ for some $f \in C_b$. All that remains is to show that
$f(t) \to 0$.

Note that $|f(t)| \le |f(t)-f_n(t)| + |f_n(t)| \le \|f-f_n\| + |f_n(t)|$.

Let $\epsilon >0$ then choose $n$ such that 
$\|f-f_n\| < { 1\over 2} \epsilon$.

Now choose $T$ such that for $t \ge T$ we have  $|f_n(t)| < { 1\over 2} \epsilon$, hence
$|f(t)| \le \epsilon.$

Comment: What exactly does $f(t)$ mean?

Comment: The function $f$ evaluated at $t$???

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm confused by the difference between $f$ and $f(t)$ in the different norms

Comment: I'm not sure what you are confused about. There is only one norm $\| \cdot \|$ above. The other is the absolute value of $f(t)$, etc.